# Hyperparameter Tuning with Keras / Tensorflow for multivariate time series regression

Tags: time-series, keras, hyperparameter, multivariate-regression

### **The model**

I am training a dense feed-forward NN using the Keras API on Tensorflow.
Each sample of the training set defines $\mathbf{X_t}$ and $\mathbf{Y_t}$ of an observed time period $t\in T$. Input vectors $\mathbf{X_t}$ consist of multiple predictor values, Output vector $\mathbf{Y_t}$ are multiple target values, which need to be predicted as a regression model. The model is in high-dimensional space and non-linear.

NOTE: I am aware, that time series characteristics eg. trend, seasonality is not addressed with such a model

### **The question**

For setting the hyperparameters (eg. using Grid Search or Bayesian Tuning):

**WHICH HYPERPARAMETERS SHOULD BE CONSIDERED IN WHICH ORDER?**

Are there any references (publications?) which propose which hyperparameters to tune in which order?

For now I use an iterative approach similar to this:

[edit: Revised the steps]

*Step 1 - grid to find basic training paramaters:*

- k-fold splits = [10, 20, .., 60]
- batch size = [5, 10, .., 50]
- epochs = [5, 15, .., 40]

*Step 2 - grid to define the basic NN layout:*

- layer 1 units = [80, 120, 160, 200]
- layer 2 units = [0, 80, 120, 160, 200]
- layer 3 units = [0, 80, 120, 160, 200]
- layer 1 dropout = [.2, .4, .6]
- layer 2 dropout = [.2, .4, .6]
- final 3 dropout = [.2, .4, .6]

*Step 3 - Survey: How big is the influence of the above tuned parameters?*

- Mean and deviation of each parameter
- Printing best sets
- Manually checking plot's (eg. density plots of multilple values)
- Freezing 'best' parameters

*Step 4&5 - (same as 2&3) with additional parameters*

- activation layers 1-3 = [relu, elu]
- activation final layer = [relu, elu, linear]
- kernel_initializer layers 1-3 = [glorot_uniform, uniform, normal]
- optimizer = [Adam, Nadam, RMSprop]
- loss = [MSE, RMSE]

This approach leads to alright results but feels a bit random.

**So any ideas / papers which hyperparameters to tune in which order for such a multivariate regression model? Maybe also promising settings?**

Also see:
[What's your methodology of tuning neural network hyperparameters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285791/whats-your-methodology-of-tuning-neural-network-hyperparameters)

Of course there exist auto-tuners and multiple publications focusing on the tuning of specific parameters, or specifically on convolutional NN's  - but unfortunately I am not aware of a holistic concept in the domain of regression.

And yes: Its a cross-topic with some programming aspects, but I would be pleased not to discuss this :)

---

For the ones interested you will find the code attached:

```
from ModelBuilder import *


def main():

    FILENAMES = {
        'filename_configurations':          'Data/Input/X.csv',
        'filename_orders':                  'Data/Input/Y.csv',
    }

    PICKLEPATH = 'pickle.pickle'
    PICKLEINPUT = None

    # dict with parameters
    GRIDPARAMS = {
        'kfold_splits':     [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'batch_size':       [2],
        'layer_1':          [120],
        'dropout_1':        [0.2],
        'layer_2':          [300],
        'dropout_2':        [0.3],
        'layer_3':          [0],
        'dropout_3':        [0],
        'optimizer':        ['Adam', 'Nadam', 'RMSprop'],
        'loss':             ['logcosh', 'binary_crossentropy', 'mean_squared_error'],
        'activation_1':     ['relu', 'elu'],
        'activation_2':     ['relu', 'elu'],
        'kernel_initializer_1': ['glorot_uniform', 'uniform', 'normal'],
        'kernel_initializer_2': ['glorot_uniform', 'uniform', 'normal']
    }

    model = ANN()
    results = model.gridsearch(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        steps=10,
        jobs=4,     # to avoid CPU overflow dont use more then 5
        pickle_path=PICKLEPATH,
        pickle_input=PICKLEINPUT,
        grid_params=GRIDPARAMS,
    )
```

The class of the model

````
from itertools import product
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np
import math
import pickle
import time


class ANN:
    def __init__(self):
        """The class fits and trains multiple Tensorflow nets

        :param filenames: Dictionary pointing to ext source data
        """

    def gridsearch(self, x, y, steps, jobs, pickle_path, pickle_input=None, grid_params=None,):

        if pickle_input is None:
            # Generate product of all parameters
            parameters = self._dict_product(grid_params)
            print('{} Parameter sets are tested'.format(len(parameters)))

        else:
            with open(pickle_input, 'rb') as handle:
                print('Loading pickle file {}'.format(pickle_input))
                parameters = pickle.load(handle)

        # Loop over params as long as uncalculated ('metric'=None) elements are present
        while sum(param['metric'] == None for param in parameters) > 0:

            # Define parameter Sets to be passed to parallel fitter
            idx_to_calculate = [i for i in range(len(parameters)) if parameters[i]['metric'] == None][:steps]
            print(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
            print("Solving instances", min(idx_to_calculate) + 1, "to", max(idx_to_calculate) + 1)

            # Run parallel fitter
            sol = Parallel(n_jobs=jobs, verbose=True)(delayed(self._single_fit)(x, y, params) for params in [(parameters[i]) for i in idx_to_calculate])

            # Write results into List
            for i in idx_to_calculate:
                parameters[i]['metric'] = sol[i-min(idx_to_calculate)]

            # Pickle List
            with open(pickle_path, 'wb') as handle:
                pickle.dump(parameters, handle)

        return parameters

    def _single_fit(self, x, y, params):

        import os
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
        from tensorflow import keras
        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

        # Clean Data
        x = x.values
        y = y.values

        # Empty result ndarry
        predictions = np.zeros(y.shape)

        # Generate k-fold splits
        kf = KFold(n_splits=params['kfold_splits'])
        for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
            x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

            # Define Layer
            layer = []
            layer.append(keras.layers.Dense(params['layer_1'], activation=params['activation_1'], kernel_initializer=params['kernel_initializer_1'], input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
            layer.append(keras.layers.Dropout(params['dropout_1']))
            if params['layer_2'] > 0:
                layer.append(keras.layers.Dense(params['layer_2'], activation=params['activation_2'], kernel_initializer=params['kernel_initializer_2']))
                layer.append(keras.layers.Dropout(params['dropout_2']))
            if params['layer_3'] > 0:
                layer.append(keras.layers.Dense(params['layer_3'], activation='relu'))
                layer.append(keras.layers.Dropout(params['dropout_3']))
            layer.append(keras.layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))

            model = keras.Sequential(layer)

            # Compile and fit model
            model.compile(loss=params['loss'], optimizer=params['optimizer'], metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
            model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=params['batch_size'], epochs=25, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
            predictions[test_index] = model.predict(x_test)

        # Calculate RMSE
        return self._get_mean_rmse(y, predictions)

    @staticmethod
    def _arguments_product(kwargs):
        keys = kwargs.keys()
        vals = kwargs.values()
        for instance in product(vals):
            yield dict(zip(keys, instance))

    @staticmethod
    def _dict_product(dicts):
        dicts['metric'] = [None]
        return [dict(zip(dicts, x)) for x in product(*dicts.values())]

    @staticmethod
    def _get_mean_rmse(observations, predictions):
        cols = observations.shape[1]
        rows = observations.shape[0]
        rmse_per_col = []
        for col in range(0, cols):
            sums = 0
            for row in range(0, rows):
                sums += (observations[row, col]-predictions[row, col])**2
            rmse_per_col.append(math.sqrt(sums/rows))
        return sum(rmse_per_col) / len(rmse_per_col)

```
````

Comment: Number of folds in cross validation is not a hyperparameter you should tune. It is part of your evaluation, and set based on how strong you need it to be. Almost noone goes above 10.It must be the same for all compared models

Comment: Why are you using a neural network? Have you tried a RandomForest and compared results? They usually do well with no hyperparameter tuning, or tuning just min_samples_leaf. If that does not do well enough, then try Gradient Boosting, which also has much fewer hyperparameters